# What does option "--resolve-image" in "docker stack" mean exactly?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

The document goes

> Query the registry to resolve image digest and supported platforms ("always"|"changed"|"never")

But what does each value mean?

Answer (score 3):

These values means the changes in images condition while deploying the stack. for example below is very small stack to deploy:

```
version: "3.3"

services:

    redis:
        image: redis:3.2.8

docker stack deploy -c test.yaml --resolve-image changed test
```

above stack deployed with the image condition= changes, means if docker found any change in image it will redeploy the stack. so three condition means:

```
1- always: always re-deploy irrespective of any changes
2- changed: only when if there are any changes in images
3- never: never irrespective of images changes
```

Hope It helps you to understands this.

Comment: If I change redis:3.2.8 to redis:3.2.9, then the service will redeploy for always and changed, but not for never. But want if redis remains 3.2.8, and I do upload a new image with the same tag?

Comment: what i meant by image condition = changes is that, hash value of the images changes then these condition will trigger. As you asked if you change tag of the same Image it will change the hash value of the image so condition will trigger.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating @Vinod - do you know whether this will re-deploy each services in the stack or just the once where the image changed?

Comment: I did some light testing and it seems that indeed only those services get updated for which the image changed.